# when using if loop vs while loop, why did if-loop break earlier

Tags: python, sorting, while-loop

I was trying to solve a problem of finding a subsequence of an array where the sum of the highest elements are greater than the remaining elements, for example:

[4, 3, 10, 9, 8] is [10, 9] because their sum is greater than [4, 3, 8]

(the entire problem can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-subsequence-in-non-increasing-order/) )

For my code, after sorting the numbers in non-descending order, I started with an if loop:

```
        sorty = []
        i = 0


        for n in nums:
            if sum(sorty) <= sum(nums):
                sorty.append(nums[-1])
                nums.pop()
            else: 
                break

        return sorty
```

But this didn't work for an array like [8, 8], because the output was `sorty = [8]`, `nums = [8]` instead of `sorty = [8, 8]`.  I ended up using a while loop instead.  I don't understand, since the if loop should continue running even if the first list equals the second list, so why did it stop after the sum of the two lists were equal? I used the <= operand.

Is there a, underlying difference inherent in if vs while loops that I'm missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop", `if-elif-else` statements are not looping constructs, they are *branching* constructs. Did you mean for-loop?

Comment: Anyway, your issue here is that you are modifying your list while iterating over it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my mistake, I did not mean a loop, I meant if-else statement. So, if the condition is met while modifying the if statement, then it will not complete the if statement?

Comment: Repeatedly summing subsequences is unnecessarily slow. Start with `sorty_sum = 0` and `total_sum = sum(nums)`, then add/subtract `n` as necessary at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through an array that you are modifying. Creating a range with the initial length to use as iterator should work to avoid unexpected behaviors:

```
sorty = []
i = 0
for n in range(len(nums)):
            print(n)
            if sum(sorty) <= sum(nums):
                sorty.append(nums[-1])
                nums.pop()
            else: 
                break

return sorty
```